# Cannot validate locally stored image in Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
        $path = file('test.png');
        $data = ['image' => $path];
        $rules = array('image' => 'required|image');
        $validator = Validator::make($data,$rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {

            $messages = $validator->messages();
            $this->info($messages);

        }
        else {
           
           $this->info($message)

       }
```

Whenever I try to validate an Image that is locally stored in my project, it would give me this error `{"image":["validation.required"]}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `$path = public_path('test.png');`

Comment: It's not supposed to be in the public folder anyways, but even when I tried It still didn't work

Comment: it is expecting there to be an instance of a `UploadedFile`, `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`, or `File`, `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`, type object, not a path